# Polymer: apply style to an element under Shadow DOM

Tags: html, css, polymer, polymer-2.x

I have using Polymer 2.0. I need to apply style for a class under Shadow DOM.

**If the case is like** (`iron-dropdown` is under shadow-root):

```
<paper-menu-button>

#shadow-root
<iron-dropdown></iron-dropdown>

</paper-menu-button>
```

*Style for `iron-dropdown` we can write like this:*

```
paper-menu-button {
   --iron-dropdown: {   
     overflow:visible;
   }
}
```

**But, In this case:**

```
<paper-menu-button>

#shadow-root
<iron-dropdown>
<div class="dropdown-content"> content </div>
</iron-dropdown>

</paper-menu-button>
```

**How can we apply style for class** `.dropdown-content`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<paper-menu-button>` allows styling the inner `<iron-dropdown>` and `.dropdown-content` with CSS properties (i.e., `--paper-menu-button-content` and `--paper-menu-button-dropdown`, respectively):

```
<dom-module id="x-foo">
  <template>
    <style>
      paper-menu-button {
        /* applies to inner iron-dropdown */
        --paper-menu-button-dropdown: {
          overflow: visible;
        };

        /* applies to inner .dropdown-content */
        --paper-menu-button-content: {
          box-shadow: 5px 10px 20px lightblue;
          overflow: visible;
        };
      }
    </style>

    <paper-menu-button>
    ...
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/YYVvPV?editors=1010)

The [`<paper-menu-button>` docs on styling](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-menu-button#user-content-styling) may list other CSS properties you might find useful.

Answer (score -1):

you could use inline styles to style `.dropdown-content`.

not nice but effective

Comment: we cannot write inline style to a class under Shadow DOM.

Comment: it's not possible to do `<div class="dropdown-content" style="overflow: visible"> content </div>`?